# pandas mean value data frame changes initial data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have been stumbling upon a problem and have no idea why it behaves like that.
I have pandas DataFrame with hourly values and wanted to make a new DataFrame out of this with the monthly mean values for each hour.
This is one part of the code I used:

```
flussmonthly=fluss2 
flussmonthly['2015-06-01 00:00:00' : '2015-06-30 23:00:00']=fluss2['2015-06-01 00:00:00' : '2015-06-30 23:00:00'].mean()
```

where fluss2 is the initial DataFrame with the hourly values and flussmonthly should in the end be the DataFrame with the monthly mean values. however, whenever I apply this code the DataFrame flussmonthly has the average value of this month for each hour, but also the DataFrame fluss2 has. 
I have no idea why. How can it be that also the DataFrame fluss2 changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
flussmonthly=fluss2
```

You are not copying the data frame, but just [copying the reference](https://helloacm.com/copy-by-reference-or-value-in-python/). If you want `flussmonthly` to be a different, independent data frame containing the same data as `fluss2` the you should do:

```
flussmonthly = fluss2.copy()
```

Then changing `flussmonthly` will not affect `fluss2`.